# Yui panel change style when closed

Tags: yui

**i am using the yui panles i set the body overflow to hidden when open the panel how can i return the overflow to scroll when the panel closed or when click on its close link**

YUI().use('yui2-container', 'yui2-dragdrop', 'event', function(Y) {

```
    var YAHOO = Y.YUI2;

    var modal = new YAHOO.widget.Panel("content", {
        width: "240px",
        fixedcenter: true,
        close: true,
        draggable: true,
        zindex: 4,
        modal: true,
        visible: false
    });
modal.render(document.body);

    Y.one('#show').on('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("content4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("reader_body").style.overflow="hidden";

        modal.show();

        var exit = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('container-close');
         YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(exit, "click", exitFunction);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a save button and put an event listener on it that calls a function:

```
var saveButton = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('save_'+id);
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(saveButton, "click", replaceTxtAction,{'id':someid});

function replaceTxtAction(e,data){
   TEXTAREA[data.id].hide();
}
```

and mine didnt properly hide in IE8, so I just used a addClass('hidden'), where hidden = display: none;